# JUnit 5 test with a field annotated as `@RegisterExtension` doesn't work in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, junit5

I have a `JUnit 5` test class written in `Java` that uses a field annotated as `@RegisterExtension`, and it works just fine:

```
class RegisterExtensionTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    LoggingExtension log = new LoggingExtension(RegisterExtensionTest.class);

    @Test void demoTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I convert it to Kotlin:

```
class RegisterExtensionTest {

     @RegisterExtension
     var log = LoggingExtension(RegisterExtensionTest::class.java)

     @Test
     fun demoTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the `LoggingExtension` doesn't run any more. Why?

Comment: Meta: for reference, markdown multiline codeblocks don't work here. Use 4 spaces instead. Inline using backticks does work, but using three to create blocks isn't supported

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As documented [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic-static-fields-kotlin), just add a `@JvmField` annotation to the field, and it works.

```
class RegisterExtensionTest {

     @JvmField
     @RegisterExtension
     var log = LoggingExtension(RegisterExtensionTest::class.java)

     @Test
     fun demoTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The **extension field has to be public** (and JUnit doesn't warn you if it isn't), but in Kotlin, a property creates a private field and a getter in the byte code, so JUnit doesn't see it.

Comment: Please note that this is also documented in the upcoming 5.3 User Guide: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic-static-fields-kotlin

Comment: Thanx @SamBrannen! Maybe it would also be possible to warn instead, or even allow private fields?

Comment: JUnit ignores `private` code elements out of principle. So I don't foresee that ever changing, but you could certainly create a GitHub issue if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: With regard to warnings for improper configuration, see https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/242

Comment: I wish I could +10 an answer!

Comment: In my case, I had to add a `final` as well.